# UPDATE and SELECT a row in the same transaction

Tags: sql-server, database

Is it possible to `UPDATE` a row and then `SELECT` the updated data from the very same row inside the same transaction without fear of a deadlock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`OUTPUT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to do this.

```
Update table_name
set col1='some_value'
output inserted.*
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you run in the same transaction both statements they shouldn't deadlock between them

If you are afraid of deadlocking with other transactions, you should minimize the locking caused by your transactions, using a indexed `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` and avoiding `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level if possible. (ReadCommitted do the trick for you?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should be fine.  A deadlock occurs when two separate SQL sessions try to access the same record at the same time.  Because the Update and Select are happening in the same Transaction, it will force them to happen sequentially.  However, if multiple sources are running your Transaction, that could cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

To SELECT inserted value use the following query

```
UPDATE SET maths = 20,biology = 21 OUTPUT INSERTED.maths, INSERTED.biology WHERE student_id = 12
```

To SELECT previous value use

```
UPDATE SET maths = 20 OUTPUT DELETED.maths WHERE student_id = 12
```